# Create Nested Build for object rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, build, nested-attributes

My JSON API is like below,

```
{ "schedule_id": "1",
  "latitude" : 17.4327,
  "longitude" : 78.4302,
  "device_id": "123test",
  "audit_compliances":[
    {
      "value": "Yes",
      "score": 10,
      "remarks": "some remarks",
      "private_remarks": "some remarks",
      "check_point_id": 1,
    "audit_compliance_documents":[{
      "score": 10,
      "remarks": "some remarks",
     }]
   }]
```

i have a relations for that DB i want to save all this records at once so i want to initialize the object with details and build inner objects along with that. Started building like this but how can i build inner build for documents.

```
submission = Submission.new(audit_schedule_id: params[:schedule_id],
  latitude: params[:latitude], longitude: params[:longitude], 
  device_id: params[:device_id])
params[:audit_compliances].each do |audit_compliance|
  submission.audit_compliances.build(
    value: audit_compliance[:value],
    score: audit_compliance[:score],
    remarks: audit_compliance[:remarks],
    private_remarks: audit_compliance[:private_remarks],
    check_point_id: audit_compliance[:check_point_id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

pass your json param in submission params directly
like this

```
 params[:submission] = json_params;

 Submission.create(params[:submission]);
```

It will create both if your mapping is correct........